# Fresh Kubuntu 15.04 installation hangs on boot

Tags: boot, kubuntu, macbook, 15.04

I've just done a fresh installation of Kubuntu 15.04 on my Macbook Pro retina (june 2014) and it seems to get stuck somewhere during booting.

I suspect it has troubles with the wireless adapter in my macbook as that one didn't pop-up during the live session.

When I switched to a shell by using Ctrl + Alt + F1(fn) it said "error: /dev/sdb: no medium found". There is no medium /dev/sdb and my USB stick was mounted on /dev/sdc.

Could someone help me out? I don't know what the source of this problem is.

What it looks like now:

[image: Picture of screen]

Comment: I had the same error on my desktop PC. I usually got the hanging while/after installing the upgrades. After a few attempts at reinstall, the problem disappeared. It doesn't seem to be related to the "no medium found" messages, as those still appear on my console.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Ubuntu for the first time and have the same error while installing it on my system from scratch. I just had to wait for 2 minutes when the PC shows this error 4 times: `error:/dev/sdb: no medium found` and then it loads normally.